# How can I use roslyn from a t4 template to parse the current solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, t4, roslyn

How can I get an instance of `VisualStudioWorkspace` for the current session from within a T4-template?  I want this to be able to parse source files within the current solution (i.e. the solution in which the .tt file resides).

From a VS package I can use `GetService(SComponentModel)` and get the workspace instance from that, but this seems to generate an error in the T4-file when using the following code:

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)this.Host;
var comp = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel)) as IComponentModel;
```

The error returned is: 
`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.ComponentModel' in Assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.Implementation, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.`

Comment: IIRC, T4 does not run in the VS process; this may not be possible.

Comment: Hmm.. that sounds annoying, and a bit strange. After all you can access the FileCodeModel from the DTE within a T4-template, and I thought this was implemented on top of Roslyn these days?

Comment: Either I'm wrong, or that only work via cross-process COM marshalling.

Comment: That's dissapointing. So in that case, a single file generator in a VSPackage is the only option for generating code in this case, requiring that every developer installs a VS extension?

Comment: I was completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the VS `IServiceProvider` from T4 by setting `hostspecific="true"`, then casting `this.Host` to `IServiceProvider`.

[Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg604090)

However, that won't actually work, since your T4 code runs in a separate AppDomain, and MEF and Roslyn objects won't work with that.  Injecting a `MarshalByRefObject` into the main VS AppDomain may work.

Comment: Yes, was aware of that. However, if I try to get the `SComponentModel` service (to get my `VisualStudioWorkspace`) I get an error saying that some type is not serializable.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I used and the error I got.

Comment: @DeCaf: Ah; it looks like T4 runs in a separate AppDomain (which makes sense, since it ought to be unloaded).   You're out of luck, unless you write a `MarshalByRefObject` wrapper and load it into the original AppDomain (which may not be easy).

Comment: I was afraid of that. Guess I'll have to write my generation code as an VSIX package instead then.  If you update your answer with this info I'll mark this question as answered. Thanks for your input!